# Import a txt.file with non-numerical variables and no separators

Tags: r

Good Morning

I have a large dataset (~ 500MB) stored in a .txt-file with numerical and non-numerical variables which I need to read into R. Unfortunately there are no separators between the values of the variables and there is no header file.

However, I know the dataset's structure which specifies which column belongs to which variable.

I can't work with read.fwf, because the dateset is non-numerical; but their width is the same for all cases.

I am new in R so I don't know How could I import this dataset. I appreciate any help

Comment: Does the readr package's function read_fwf work for you?

Comment: `read.fwf`can read a data set even if it's not all numeric. Have you already tried to run it? If so, did it return an error?

Comment: Yes, I already try it and it return an error related to "non numeric values".

Comment: What I am doing is: 1) use read table, header=FALSE, sep="\t" (so the dataset is load as a one variable dataset, because it does not have tab anywhere).              2) Generate all the variables using substring.

Comment: However, this solution is not good because I need to name the variables any time I have another structure. Thats why a way to load the dataset similar to read.fwf, or a comprensible example of how we can load data using read.fwf when we have non-numeric data works